# magento remove breadcrumbs from home only with local.xml

Tags: xml, magento, breadcrumbs

Is it possible to remove the breadcrumbs from only the homepage, with 1 local.xml in magento? 
How can I do it?

I've tried this, but it's not working... :(

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `reference`.  `remove` will find the block named `breadcrumbs` and remove it wherever it may be.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</cms_index_index>
```

Also try adding

```
<remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
```

To your home page's CMS layout updates in the admin.  It could be an issue with your `local.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to add to the Layout Update XML of your homepage CMS page:

```
 <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
```